# 400 Status with "invalid grant" error using Google API's on Java

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I have a backend process that attempts to auto-create Google Apps users that was working (without any changes as far as I can tell) up until last week. The code from other questions similar to this one *seemed* to be irrelevant or too different from mine in regarding the code being used to be helpful.

The following code is what is *supposed* to generate the account:

```
            private static String GMAIL_DOMAIN = "obfuscated.com";
            private static String GAPPS_EMAIL = "1234567890-a978g6e789gage96gaf6ag997gawg@developer.gserviceaccount.com";
            private static JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory
                .getDefaultInstance();

            HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport
                    .newTrustedTransport();
            List<String> scopes = new ArrayList<String>();
            scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
            scopes.add(DirectoryScopes.ADMIN_DIRECTORY_GROUP_MEMBER);
            File p12 = new File("/opt/gapps.p12");
            GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                    .setTransport(httpTransport).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                    .setServiceAccountId(GAPPS_EMAIL)
                    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12)
                    .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)
                    .setServiceAccountUser("obfus@cated.com")
                    .build();
            Directory service = new Directory.Builder(httpTransport,
                    JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("Obfuscated")
                    .build();

            // All of these local variables are set further up in the code.
            com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User gappsUser = new com.google.api.services.admin.directory.model.User();
            UserName gappsUsername = new UserName();
            gappsUsername.setGivenName(fname);
            gappsUsername.setFamilyName(lname);
            gappsUsername.setFullName(fname + " " + lname);
            gappsUser.setName(gappsUsername);
            gappsUser.setPrimaryEmail(username);
            gappsUser.setPassword(password);

            Directory.Users.Insert gappsRequest = service.users().insert(
                    gappsUser);
            gappsRequest.execute();
```

The following is a truncated stack trace that is returned (the line of my class that's indicated is the last line):

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{ "error" : "invalid_grant" } at
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
at
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
at
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
at
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
at
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859) at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
at
com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

I have verified that the p12 file is still present and that everything matches as far as the service account credentials are concerned. I'm not sure what could have changed over the last week or so, but the lack of fruits of my research labors has left me not knowing where to look or what to do to remedy the situation. If anyone else has experienced something similar I would definitely appreciate the help!